# Does Fetch as Google have a charchters / lines limit? And does it matter?

Tags: seo, html, fetch-as-google, page-size

I have a test page with text only. No JS. No CSS. Just the `html`, `head`, `body` and `p` tags and a lot of *lorem ipsum* text.

Now when I try to use Fetch as Google tool, the HTTP response is cutted at the 1562 line. If I remove content so it's shorter then 1562 lines, it renders all the content until the last `</html>` closing tag, but if the HTML is more then 1562 lines, it will be cut at the 1562 line.

So my questions are:

1. Is this a known limit? (Didn't find any info about that anywhere)
2. Does it need to worry me if my site has more then 1562 lines and Fetch as Google shows me my site only until that line (SEO speaking)? I mean could it be that the site is not rendering right on the "Fetch as google" but still will have good ranking? Or is it really to way google fetches the page?

Comment: 1562 lines of rendered output, or 1562 lines of HTML source? This is probably just a limitation of the "Fetch as Google" tool, it's unlikely to relate to Google search and the quantity indexed - just my hunch.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite, 1562 lines of rendered output. that's actually the reason i'm asking, because this is my guess too and i want to know if i can rely on it... but i need some source or something so i can move on with this situation.

Comment: Could be a 'time out' due to the length of the file?

Comment: If i would know that it will answer my question :)

Answer (score 1):

> cutted at the 1562 line

And how long is the whole source code?

1. All limits are individually set by Google.
2. Yes, it needs to worry you. You should ask yourself, why Google set a limit on your page. This question bears a couple of questions, like:

   - is it *really* needful, that you page has such length?
   - is your page too slow?
   - is your page blocking Googlebot on the codeline, where it cuts the fetching?

Comment: Thanks @Evgeniy! About your questions: As I wrote, it doesn't matter the length, i have test page here: [link](http://elementest.packale.co.il/test.html) that i was trying to change his length and it doesn't matter as long as it's more then 1562 rows.  this link is just a test page but the site that i'm working on really needs to be very long (to explain why would be very long also :).  the test page isn't slow at all as you can see in the link but the original site isn't slow either.  you can see in that link that there is nothing in the code that will block googlebot.

Comment: i still don't understand, what do you expect to see as fetch results? You have a test page with just a `<p></p>` as markup and `lorem ipsum` as content - there is just nothing to fetch...

Comment: What do you mean there is nothing to fetch there is a lot of text, and it should fetch it all, unless it has some limit of lines or characters fetched, and this is my simple question.